# Windows Printer Driver locations after clicking Windows Update

Tags: windows-7, drivers, printer

Ok I know that windows 7 store all drivers in C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\

However, when adding a new printer and clicking the windows update button more printers show up, but then when I check in C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\ they are not there. So where does windows actually store these new drivers?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In win7 you can use Printmanagement.msc console, there you will find all printers drivers installed in your system and their location

Comment: Printmanagement.msc is a handy console alright, but I am more insterested in the drivers that are not installed. Anyway I found out that that list is only for selecting what drivers you want to download rather than being a list of downloaded drivers.